# Education List or Educations List?

Tags: grammatical-number

As the title asks, is "education list" grammatically correct or is "educations list" correct. I'm using this to try to describe a part of a website's interface where there is a list, populated by multiple items related to a person's education.

Comment: And does each list item have a single item or multiple items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Education List" is correct. Unlike in other languages, there is rarely concordance or agreement between the adjective and noun form in this kind of binomial, where "list" is the noun and "education" describes it. Moreover, "education" is not often used in plural.

Proper usage can be illustrated by looking at other types of list, for example one which I come across most days in my work is a "list of partners", for which the usual heading is "Partner List". Or a "list of contacts" -> "Contact List". Etc.